# Form::Open Action Variable

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to wrap a `Form::Open` within a foreach statement and call the `Controller` from a variable. It seems with the following code it will not return the controller information within the foreach statement.

```php
    <?php
    $list = ['Sub_Locations','Networks','Equipment','Site_Visits'];
    $get_modules = DB::table('modules')->whereIn('name', $list)->get();
    foreach ($get_modules as $create){
    ?>

       @la_access("$create->name", "create")

    <div class="modal fade" id="Add<?php echo $create->name; ?>" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Add <?php echo $create->name; ?></h4>
            </div>


            {!! Form::open(['action' => 'LA\$create->controller@store', 'id' => 'customer-add-form']) !!}

            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="box-body">
                    <?php $form = Module::get($create->name); ?>
                    @la_form($form)
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                {!! Form::submit( 'Submit', ['class'=>'btn btn-success']) !!}
            </div>
            {!! Form::close() !!}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

        @endla_access
      <?php
         }
          ?>
```

Comment: Why are you mixing Blade templating and PHP tags? You can easily do a foreach with Blade with `@foreach/@endforeach`. I'm not sure what you mean by calling the controller, since you have code directly in your template (I hope it's the template) and not in a separate controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a number of issues that are stopping this from working the way you want it to.

As @aynber said, it would make it more clear / easier if you were to use blade tags all the way through.  Less confusing.  So,

```
@foreach 
   // loop of forms
@endforeach
```

The next issue is that you have a non-resolvable entity within your call to `Form`.  Your form structure is fine for open and close, but the stuff within is going to cause issues.  This part of the `open` line:

```
'action' => 'LA\$create->controller@store',
```

is not going to work.  You have a variable inside a single quote.  As this is inside your blade action, use standard **PHP** notation to get to the right path.  Alternately, you can call to a route if it is easier.  Here is an example:

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => 'yourNamedRoute.store', 'id'=>'somethingX']) !!}
```

The next issue that needs attention is your id on the form:

```
'id' => 'customer-add-form'
```

As you are in a `foreach` loop, this is going to create multiple forms with the same id (`customer-add-form`) all on the same page.  This will create problems as well.

So... hopefully this will give you a few starting points to help you to solve your issue.  This is not meant as an exhaustive answer to copy and paste; you'll have to do some bug hunting, but it will perhaps help you to get things fixed.

Answer (score 0):

```
    {!! Form::open(['action' => "LA\'$create->controller'@store", 'id' => 'customer-add-form']) !!}
```

This seems to display the correct string now but the single quotes and messing the patch up. Any ideas?

Comment: {!! Form::open(['action' => "LA\\$create->controller@store", 'id' => "\\$create->name-add-form"]) !!}
 This worked!

Comment: Yes, that works, and also, you can use standard PHP dot notation, like `'LA\'.$create->etc`  :)